# When will the destructor be called?

Tags: c++, class, templates, destructor, smart-pointers

```
#include <memory> 
#include <iostream>

class Token { public:
  Token() { std::cout << "Token()"; }
  ~Token() { std::cout << "~Token()"; }
};

template <class T> 
std::unique_ptr<T> foo(T t0) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(t0)); };

int main() {
    Token&& t = Token();
    auto ptr = foo<Token>(t); 
    return 0;
}
```

On which occasions will the destructor be called?

I think it will be called firstly when we call `Token()`, it creates a temporary object which is destructed immediately, then in the `foo()` function when `t0` is destructed, and then when `main()` ends, and `ptr` goes out of scope.

But my friend says otherwise, so how will it actually be?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: `t` extends the lifetime of the temporary `Token()` until the reference goes out of scope, so it should be the last one to be destroyed.

Comment: @drescherjm The code -- as posted -- doesn't help you figure out which destructor call belongs to which object. Furthermore, you see more destructor calls than constructors because two of the constructions are copy/move constructions (one implicit, one explicit) which fail to print out any diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a scope ends and the automatic objects of that scope are destroyed, their destructors will be called in the reverse order the objects were created:

```
int main() {
    Token&& t = Token(); // Token1 constructed
                         // lifetime of Token1 extended because it was bound to t
    auto ptr = foo<Token>(t); // creates a copy of Token1 for the argument of foo: Token2
                              // Token3 constructed by foo in dynamic memory
                              // and bound to ptr, which
                              // resides in automatic memory
    // Token2 (temporary copy) is automatically destroyed
    return 0;
    // Last automatic object is destroyed: ptr
    //   thus, uniqe_ptr destroys Token3
    // t is destroyed. This destroys Token1 because
    //                 its lifetime-extending reference
    //                 went out of scope
}
```

### Demo

If you modify your Token class slightly you can observe this live:

```
class Token {
  inline static int C = 1;
  int c = C++;
public:
  Token(Token const&) : Token() {}
  Token(Token&&) : Token() {}
  Token() { std::cout << "Token(" << c << ")\n"; }
  ~Token() { std::cout << "~Token(" << c << ")\n"; }
};
```

Output:

```
Token(1)
Token(2)
Token(3)
~Token(2)
~Token(3)
~Token(1)
```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/safs7G8Tf))

Answer (score 0):

@bitmask's explanation about life-time is pretty clear. Besides, if you want to get the best performance, maybe you could implement the move constructor for your `class Token`, and then:

```
template <class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> foo(T& t0) {                 // pass-by-reference
    return std::make_unique<T>(std::move(t0));
};
```

As you have used rvalue reference `Token&& t` to extend the temporary `Token` object's lifetime in function `int main()` and the rvalue reference `t` is a lvalue, so `auto foo(T &)` will deduce `T` as `class Token` and accept `t` as its parameter `t0` according to [Overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). Furthermore, `std::move` cast lvalue `t0` to rvalue reference and `std::make_unique` call the constructor which satisfies `std::is_nothrow_constructable_v<Token,Token&&>` is `true`, the move constructor and copy constructor are both candicate functions. If you have implemented `Token(Token&&)`, move constructor will be called. Otherwise is copy constructor.